# Очереди ларавел. Редирект перед исполнением скрипта

Tags: laravel, redirect, очередь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать очереди ларавел, чтобы сначала делать редирект, а потом уже на сервере обрабатывать данные.

Делаю сервис коротких ссылок, который должен перенаправлять пользователя согласно сопоставлению ссылок (короткой - полной) на полную (сторонний ресурс) при этом еще обработать какие-то данные на основе ip.

В контроллере сначала беру информацию о короткой ссылке, достаю полную ссылку и получаю ip юзера, потом мне нужно сделать редирект и после него уже передать в очереди ip где будет запущен процесс обработки информации и занесении ее в базу.

Обязательно ли для этого настраивать сервис очередей или достаточно создать бд, как в примере ларавел. Нужна ли вообще бд или ларавел может после редиректа сразу фоном выполнять задач?

Пробовал делать так:

`$ip = 127.0.0.1;
 UnqLinkUserInfo::dispatch($ip);
return redirect()->to('example.com');`

Скрипт все равно вначале обрабатывает данные и только потом делает редирект, а не добавляет данные в очередь. Возможно я что то не так понял, но погуглив так и не нашел решения

Answer (score 0):

Тут все просто. Для начала надо настроить очередь.
Вариантов тут много и зависят от того, где лежит проект. 
Если это `VPS|VDS`, где ты имеешь root доступ к конфигурации сервера и [можешь настроить `supervisor`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker) (или другой сервис). Соответсвенно настраиваешь фоновый воркер и в `.env` файле ставишь `QUEUE_DRIVER=redis` или `QUEUE_DRIVER=database`. Хотя в версии `5.7+` эта ENV переменная называется `QUEUE_CONNECTION`;

После изменений `.env` не забывай сбрасывать кеш конфигурации `php artisan config:clear`

Когда драйвер очереди отличен от `sync` - задачи летят в соответствующее хранилище (redis,database,etc.) и подхватываются фоновым воркером.

Если у тебя обычный хостинг без вожможности настроить сервис очереди, то тебе придется писать свою реализации обработчика очереди через крон. Но это скорее **костыль**

P.S. код менять тебе не надо